# in clause in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
protected void lstGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValues=string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem li in lstGroup.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            selectedValues += li.Value+",";
        }

    }
    selectedValues = selectedValues.Trim(',');
    var accessright = (from ug in Db.VCT_USER_GROUPs
                       where ug.GROUP_ID in(selectedvalues)
                       select new
                                  {
                                      ug.GROUP_ID,
                                      ug.GROUP_NAME
                                  }).ToList();
    if (true)
    {
        dlGroup.DataSource = accessright;
        dlGroup.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Above is my code. In selectedValues variable i have values like 1,2,3 and i want to use in clause in linq  like where ug.GROUP_ID in(selectedvalues). but this is giving me error .how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You have to reverse the order and use `.Contains()`:

```
var accessright = (from ug in Db.VCT_USER_GROUPs
                    where selectedvalues.Contains(ug.GROUP_ID)
                    select new
                               {
                                   ug.GROUP_ID,
                                   ug.GROUP_NAME
                               }).ToList();
```

Note this uses `selectedvalues` as an enumberable, not a concatenated string:

```
var selectedvalues = lstGroups.Items.Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value);
```

Comment: var accessright = (from ug in Db.VCT_USER_GROUPs
                    where selectedvalues.Contains(Convert.toString(ug.GROUP_ID))
                    select new
                               {
                                   ug.GROUP_ID,
                                   ug.GROUP_NAME
                               }).ToList(); but it is giving me error “Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method”

Answer (score 0):

```
 (from ug in Db.VCT_USER_GROUPs
  where selectedvalues.Any(selectedeVal => selectedeVal == ug.GROUP_ID)
  select new
  {
     ug.GROUP_ID,
     ug.GROUP_NAME
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: selectedValues is a string variable. not showing me Any after .(operator)